# For loop to print control characters

Tags: vba

Alright, so I am editing a Macro for Reflection Workspace Terminal Emulator. I have a macro (it is long and not necessarily relevant, I can post the full code if anyone wants, it is about a page)

At the very end of the macro, a "Good Morning" Message is printed, and then also the value of a string variable named `myName`. This works fine.

What I want to do is then use a `For` loop to print a number of control characters (tab) equal to the amount printed in the `Good Morning User`. Here is the code I have so far:

```
Dim X As Integer

For i = 1 To i = (13 + Len(myName)) 'Good Morning + a space character will always = 13
ibmCurrentScreen.SendKeys (ControlKeyCode_Tab)
Next i

End Sub
```

I would use the Chr() function to print the control characters, but it seems that this particular program uses `ControlKeyCode_X` to print them.

Comment: In many languages exist "eval" methods, that execute some code from a string. In a fast search on google I didn't find it. But I hope this word: "eval" may help you.

Comment: remove the `i = ` after `To`

Comment: Cool, that got the loop working. I figured out how to send the control character also. If you want to post that as a (really simple) answer, I can accept.

Comment: @AdamJ duly posted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `For...Next` loop in VBA is a simple single variable counter based loop and cannot have complex criteria or multiple counters like in some other languages (e.g. in C# `for(int i = 0, int j = 10; i < 10; i++, j--)`). In VBA, therefore, the `i =` after `To` is redundant because it cannot be anything other than `i`.

The 'For' loop in VBA therefore only specifies the counter once. It should be:

```
For i = startVal To endVal [step incrementVal]
    ...
Next [i]
```

- i  = variable to vary
- startVal = start value
- endVal = end value (inclusive, i.e. `To 10` will include 10 as the final value)
- incrementVal = optional value to increment/decrement by each loop
  (default = 1)

The counter is always incremented/decremented at the end of each loop then evaluated against `endVal` (i.e. for a vanilla increment by one loop, after exiting the loop it will be endValue + 1).

Note (unrelated to your situation) that you can change the value of `i` in the loop, e.g. to increment twice because of some special circumstance.

Specifying the variable with the `Next` statement is optional and has no effect on behaviour (any nested loop must always be closed before an outer loop) but is good practice for reference when you have many For...Next loops so it is clear which loop the Next is closing (although you should be religiously indenting or otherwise delineating your code)

So in your case `For i = 1 To (13 + Len(myName))` instead.